# Port activity after applying iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I've applied a rule in the iptables
(Ubuntu x64 18)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 64080 -d 172.31.132.86 -j DNAT --to-destination 149.154.167.50:80
sudo iptables -t nat -v -L OUTPUT -n --line-number

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    57677 3785K DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2       79  4740 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.31.132.86        tcp dpt:64080 to:149.154.167.50:80
```

The question is that I don't understand should I see any activity on my local port or not?

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -d any port 64080 -q
or
sudo tcpdump port 64080
```

Nothing happens when I do:

```
wget 172.31.132.86:64080
--2019-02-27 11:42:11--  http://172.31.132.86:64080/
Connecting to 172.31.132.86:64080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-02-27 11:42:11 ERROR 404: Not Found.

or

curl 172.31.132.86:64080
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.3.33</center>
</body>
</html>
```

404 - is ok. OUTPUT works by itself.

Comment: Yes you should see activity on your local port. If you do a  `wget http://149.154.167.50/` you get an answer??

Comment: Yes, I get an answer (404 is the answer - it is fine). It is the same answer from 149.154.167.50. Means that output rule works by itself.